# Blank white Task bar after reboot, how do i get it back?

Tags: lxde

So basically i updated my raspberry pi using the jessie update but i wasn't able to finish it and turned off my computer and now the taskbar is there, but isnt responding to personal preference, (when i switch it to top or bottom), color or anything i tried seing if maybe my moniter wasnt big enough and i still saw the top of my mouse so i dont know what to do i guess i wouldnt mind so much if i still had LXTerminal but i dont so... HELP ME PLEEAASSEE

Comment: How were you updating? I would be worried what else may be broken as a result of your interrupted update. The first thing I would do is retry the update (you can use SSH to access the command line). if the update fails I would give serious thought to copying any important files to a flash drive and reflashing your SD card.

Comment: What's SSH? I'm still new to raspberry pi

Comment: It is a way to login to your Pi from another computer and have a commandline (optional GUI).